# "Значения времени полувыведения составили 1 и 2 часа соответственно" - или "значение времени полувыведения составило"?

Tags: единственное-множественное-число

Я перевожу текст на русский, и задумался над таким предложением. Как правильнее - использовать единственное число или множественное?

> Медианное значение T1/2 в группах, получавших препарат 1 и препарат 2, составило 223.3 ч и 229.7 ч соответственно.

Или

> Медианн**ые** значен**ия** T1/2 в группах, получавших препарат 1 и препарат 2, состав**или** 223.3 ч и 229.7 ч соответственно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Второй вариант:

> Медианные значения T1/2 в группах, получавших препарат 1 и препарат 2,
>   составили 223.3 ч и 229.7 ч соответственно.

Это разные виды значений, поэтому множественное число. Это как действия нескольких лиц. Значения составили 1 и 2 соответственно.